# New to coding, need help calling methods in Rally

Tags: rally

Simple question, I need to make a chart with Rally's new API. How exactly would I call the methods on this [page](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/). Specifically StartDate, EndDate, CardEsitmateTotal, and CardState.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to developing applications in ext and rally, I would suggest you take a step back and check out the guides and examples: [Rally SDK Examples](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/example).

I would also highly recommend [this YouTube video series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0h-DeIU4tQk&list=PL3PQ-IsMxhG1AXBMwOLfFyRas8kUIlrIi&index=1), which will walk you through creating an application, querying for data, using the Web Services API, creating grids and charts, etc.

These are both resources that helped me out a lot when learning how to extend the rally platform and develop custom applications.